# Set burst for bandwidth limit for a pod

Tags: kubernetes, cni

For what I know, there're two way to limit bandwidth with k8s.

First, configure the CNI with

```
{
   "type": "bandwidth",
   "capabilities": {"bandwidth": true},
   "ingressRate": 10000000,
   "ingressBurst": 10000000,
   "egressRate": 10000000,
   "egressBurst": 10000000
}
```

And second, annotate a pod with:

```
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress-bandwidth: 8M
  kubernetes.io/egress-bandwidth: 8M
```

I read through the documentations but didn't find any way to configure burst for a pod.

But the default burst is too large to make the limitation useful:

`qdisc tbf 1: dev calia2333445823 root refcnt 2 rate 8Mbit burst 256Mb lat 25.0ms`

And it seems when the CNI is configured with bandwidth limit, then pod annotations will not override the CNI's configure and take effect.

So how can I set a burst for just a pod?

---

iperf output to illustrate the burst:

server:

```
Accepted connection from 192.168.0.34, port 49470
[  5] local 192.168.203.129 port 1234 connected to 192.168.0.34 port 49472
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   246 MBytes  2060541 Kbits/sec                  (omitted)
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   935 KBytes  7657 Kbits/sec                  (omitted)
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   933 KBytes  7645 Kbits/sec                  (omitted)
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   935 KBytes  7655 Kbits/sec
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   935 KBytes  7659 Kbits/sec
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   935 KBytes  7655 Kbits/sec
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec   933 KBytes  7645 Kbits/sec
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec   932 KBytes  7637 Kbits/sec
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec   935 KBytes  7657 Kbits/sec
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec   936 KBytes  7667 Kbits/sec
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec   932 KBytes  7632 Kbits/sec
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec   935 KBytes  7659 Kbits/sec
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec   933 KBytes  7647 Kbits/sec
[  5]  10.00-11.00  sec   935 KBytes  7654 Kbits/sec
[  5]  11.00-11.15  sec   141 KBytes  7582 Kbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-11.15  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 Kbits/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-11.15  sec  10.2 MBytes  7650 Kbits/sec                  receiver
```

client:

```
[  4] local 192.168.0.34 port 49472 connected to 192.168.203.129 port 1234
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   247 MBytes  2073202 Kbits/sec    0    324 KBytes       (omitted)
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   700 KBytes  5732 Kbits/sec    0    366 KBytes       (omitted)
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  1.55 MBytes  13037 Kbits/sec    0    407 KBytes       (omitted)
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   891 KBytes  7291 Kbits/sec    0    448 KBytes
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   954 KBytes  7821 Kbits/sec    0    491 KBytes
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  1018 KBytes  8344 Kbits/sec    0    532 KBytes
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  1.06 MBytes  8858 Kbits/sec    0    573 KBytes
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  1.18 MBytes  9897 Kbits/sec    0    615 KBytes
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  1.24 MBytes  10433 Kbits/sec    0    656 KBytes
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  1.25 MBytes  10487 Kbits/sec    0    697 KBytes
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  1.25 MBytes  10488 Kbits/sec    0    766 KBytes
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 Kbits/sec    0    899 KBytes
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  1.25 MBytes  10485 Kbits/sec    0   1.03 MBytes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  10.0 MBytes  8410 Kbits/sec    0             sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  10.2 MBytes  8532 Kbits/sec                  receiver
```

---

Environment:

- Kubernetes 1.15.7
- Calico v3.11.1
- bandwidth plugin v0.8.0
- tc iproute 4.11.0-14.el7

Comment: Which kubernetes version you are using? I find out an issue with bandwidth plugins not making any changes in older k8s versions. It was fixed in 1.15. Here`s the [reference](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/f4937619a2228a71ac62270d643dc869d3765d99).

Comment: Thank you @acid_fuji I am using 1.15. I've also read this PR. In my test it actually worked, you can observe it by the tc output, the rate is exactly what I set. My problem is I can't set a burst value for specific pods, and the default burst is too high, making the bandwidth exceed the rate limit and go down under the limit after a while.

Comment: Which CNI you are using?

Comment: I'm using calico 3.11.1 with bandwidth plugin v0.8.0 @acid_fuji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately current implementation of bandwidth control does not support limiting burst for pod. I had the same results testing this. I also looked at the `cni` code on `kubernetes` github and found out that there are 
only `annotations` visible are for `ingress bandwidth` and `egress bandwidth`.

```
    bandwidthAnnotation := make(map[string]string)
    bandwidthAnnotation["kubernetes.io/ingress-bandwidth"] = "1M"
    bandwidthAnnotation["kubernetes.io/egress-bandwidth"] = "1M"
```

Since [network shaping](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) is still in alpha stage you could raise a request on [github](https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins/issues) and ask 
for this functionality.